# How can I copy/duplicate an item without getting all versions?

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6

Is there an API that will allow my to copy or duplicate and item just getting a single version?
`Item.Duplicate()` and `Item.CopyTo()` both get all numbered versions and languages.

I'm on Sitecore 6.3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`item.Versions.RemoveAll(true);` also removes the most recent version.

You could copy or duplicate the item (with all its versions) and then try something like this:

```
   private void RemovePreviousVersions(Item myItem, bool includeAllLanguages)
    {
        // get the most recent version
        Item currentVersion = myItem.Versions.GetLatestVersion();
        Item[] versions = myItem.Versions.GetVersions(includeAllLanguages);

        // loop through the item versions
        foreach(Item itemVersion in versions)
        {
            // remove the version if it is not the most recent
            if (!itemVersion.Version.Number.Equals(currentVersion.Version.Number))
            {
                itemVersion.Versions.RemoveVersion();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep, looks like I'll have to do something along these lines.  Versions.GetVersions(true) makes it somewhat easier.  Thanks, Martijn.

Answer (score 2):

I've not had to duplicate items, you could insert a new item in the tree but depends on your exact requirements.

http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/01/14/create-and-publish-items-in-sitecore/

Have you tried getting the latest version of an item in a specific language and duplicating that?

```
Item masterItem = master.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home").Versions.GetLatestVersion(Sitecore.Context.Language);
masterItem.Duplicate("newItem");
```

Or duplicate/copy and then remove the versions of the newly created item:

```
item.Versions.RemoveAll(true);
```

But you would need to check if it also removes the latest version also.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for copying only latest versions of an one item, including children. It creates a new item, creates the necessary versions and sets the fields.

```
private Item CopyLatestVersion(Item target, Item itemToCopy, string copyOfName)
    {
        var copiedItem = target.Add(copyOfName, new TemplateID(itemToCopy.TemplateID));

        var db = itemToCopy.Database;

        bool sharedFieldsPopulated = false;

        foreach (var lang in itemToCopy.Languages)
        {
            var languageVersionToCopy = 
                db.GetItem(itemToCopy.ID, lang, Sitecore.Data.Version.Latest);

            if (languageVersionToCopy.Versions.Count == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var languageVersionCopied = db.GetItem(copiedItem.ID, lang);

            //we have to check if there is already version cause when the item was created
            //Sitecore automatically creates a version already with the context language
            if (languageVersionCopied.Versions.Count == 0)
            {
                languageVersionCopied = languageVersionCopied.Versions.AddVersion();
            }

            languageVersionCopied.Editing.BeginEdit();
            foreach (Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field field in languageVersionToCopy.Fields)
            {
                if (field.HasValue
                    && (!sharedFieldsPopulated || !field.Shared)
                    && field.Name.Trim() != "")
                {
                    languageVersionCopied.Fields[field.Name].Value = field.Value;
                }
            }
            //this doesn't update the edited by field, which we don't want to set to current user 
            //but keep the original updater like in default copy to functionality
            languageVersionCopied.Editing.EndEdit(false, false);

            //during the first iteration we also copy the shared fields afterwards we don't
            sharedFieldsPopulated = true;
        }

        //recursively copying also all children
        foreach (Item child in itemToCopy.Children)
        {
            CopyLatestVersion(copiedItem, child, child.Name);
        }

        return copiedItem;
    }
```